# Cognito Forms: Fill date field with previous Date field

Tags: cognito-forms

I have a form with a number of Date fields for a time card. I would like to fill the Monday's Date field with the Pay Period Start Date field. The Monday's Date field though is inside a Section inside a Repeating Section. When I reference the Start Date field with the below I get an error.
[image: date fields in form]

```
=PayPeriodStartDate.Date
```

Here's the error:
[image]

Is there a way to be able to pull the value of the Pay Period Start Date field?

Answer (score 1):

I am a developer for [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com).

At the moment we do not have a way to pull data into a field that is outside of a section. You can pull data out of a field that is in a section.

We are working on the ability to do just what you want to, reference and pull data into a section, even when the referenced field is outside of the section. You can follow our progress on this feature over on our [Idea Board](https://trello.com/c/dKhdGujx). Although I cant give you an exact date for when this will be ready we hope to have this feature live in the next week or two. We will be sure to update this topic when the feature is released.